# How to get Linux users list from LDAP

Tags: windows, linux, active-directory, ldap

We've just linked one of our Linux host to LDAP and ActiveDirectory. Now I'm trying to  check how I get list of users and their details from within the Linux side.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve that by either typing in

```
getent passwd |less
```

or performing a LDAP search, such as

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL uid=*
```

(assuming that the bind DN and credentials are set in the ldap.conf file or you have read access to AD in other ways).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to *check* if your Linux sees the POSIX entries from a LDAP server, use

```
getent passwd
```

The output should display entries both from local `/etc/passwd` and LDAP server. If you are wondering how to get to the point, when there's something to check, [this](http://wiki.debian.org/LDAP) may prove to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ldapsearch` command line tool to query the directory server for information. For more information, see ["LDAP: Mastering ldapsearch"](https://web.archive.org/web/20131017105152/http://ldapmaven.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your Linux host is set up, `wbinfo -u` may work for you.

From the [wbinfo's manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/wbinfo.1.html):

> wbinfo - Query information from winbind daemon
>
> ...
>
> -u|--domain-users
>
> ```
>        This option will list all users available in the Windows NT domain
>        for which the winbindd(8) daemon is operating in. Users in all
>        trusted domains will also be listed. Note that this operation does
>        not assign user ids to any users that have not already been seen by
>        winbindd(8) .
> ```

Example:

```
antonio@debian:~$ wbinfo -u
administrator
antonio
guest
support_388945a0
krbtgt
antonio@debian:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux usually uses PAM for its authentication needs. It's an open architecture, so you can use the [`pam_ldap`](http://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM) module to use LDAP on Linux.