# List LDAP users on linux client?

Tags: linux, ldap

I have configured an LDAP client on my Linux machine. I am able to use `su - myldapuser` and use it. I just want to know, can I list all my LDAP users on this machine?

Referring to this link: [How to get Linux users list from LDAP](https://superuser.com/questions/376838/how-to-get-linux-users-list-from-ldap)

I tried the "getent passwd" command, but it didn't list the users. So my question is, should this command list the users on client machine also, or will this only work on the LDAP server?

Comment: What is 'linux m/c'?

Comment: linux machine..

Comment: That's a pretty uncommon abbreviation :) Did you set up `/etc/nsswitch.conf` correctly (`users: files ldap`)? And what distro are you using?

Comment: I am using Centos 6, and connecting to OpenLDAP

Comment: I referred this link: http://suresh-chandra.blogspot.in/2013/08/configuring-openldap-serverclient-on.html.. And there were no changes required in /etc/nsswitch.conf.. According to the link

Comment: So now my understanding here is that the users should be listed on the client m/c also right? using getent passwd.

Comment: Yep, they should be. But in 8 years Unix and Linux I've never seen this work without at least configuring nsswitch.conf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16221/discussion-between-dennis-and-mtak).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to list the LDAP users using `getent passwd`. However, in order for the system libraries to use LDAP you need to set up `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and the `nscd` and `nslcd` daemons. This was discussed in chat, and the following config worked for the questioner:

`/etc/nslcd.conf`:

```
uid nslcd
gid ldap
# This comment prevents repeated auto-migration of settings.
uri ldap://ldap.dg.com
base dc=dg,dc=com
ssl start_tls
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
```

(Make sure your LDAP server supports anonymous binds, otherwise you'll need to configure nslcd to use bind credentials)

`/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
passwd: files ldap
shadow: files ldap
group: files ldap
```

After a restart of the `nscd` and `nslcd` services he was able to use `getent passwd` to list the LDAP users